# HTML5: preload page and then redirect to it

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

From a mobile app I am linking to an external webpage to be opened in a browser.

However such webpage is quite big, it takes up to 5 seconds to load, so I would like to show an intermediate webpage with the message "redirecting to www.website.com".

Is there a simple way to do this in HTML5/Javascript?

Please note: when redirecting to the page, I would like the browser URL to show the destination page URL and not my intermediate page URL.

Comment: You can show the **Loading text** in the destinations page itself and keep the contect of web page hidden untill all the contect is loaded. Does that make sence ?

Comment: The destination page is on an external website, so I cannot edit it

Comment: @RayonDabre, so you mean something like: `$(window).load(function() { $('body').css('display','block'); });`?

Comment: @Daniele B,Good read: http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Comment: @odedta, yes but now its different scenario..

Comment: Yeah, the link I posted should give you a simple and quick solution for this.

Comment: @odedta, OP does not have the right to edit the code..

Comment: @RayonDabre, o_O~ that sucks.

Comment: Deleting my answer as it seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @ode you can't `.load()` a page from another domain.

Comment: @nicael, he is throwing the user to mobile browser from the app..As an extrenal URL..

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can preload an external website unless said website allows it because of the Same Origin policy. In other words, all AJAX originating from an external domain, different protocol (and I think different port) will not be allowed unless they are explicity told to.

The wikipedia link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Well title says: 'preload' and post says he's attempting to load elements before opening the website.

Comment: You need to read the question properly then..Post says **From a mobile app I am linking to an external webpage to be opened in a browser.**

Comment: Yes, that's his opening statement. If you keep reading though... Its says **However such webpage is quite big, it takes up to 5 seconds to load, so I would like to show an intermediate webpage with the message "redirecting to www.website.com".** Hence... he wants to preload the website while showing up the 5 second message then redirect to the other website.